# Identation not working with EditorConfig Sublime Text 3

Tags: github, editor, sublimetext3, editorconfig

I am using EditorConfig in Sublime Text 3. I have set up the .editorconfig file in my project root directory and it was working fine few months ago.

The indentations looks good in Sublime

[image: Sublime screenshot]

But when I push it to GitHub, the same code looks like this

[image: Github screenshot]

I removed the EditorConfig via Package Control > Remove Package.
Then reinstalled the EditorConfig package. I tried both manual way and installation via Package Control but nothing seems to work. Help me through this!

Comment: It looks like you are using tabs for indentation. Are you trying to use tabs or spaces?

Comment: I had a same problem

Comment: @chris Yes, I'm using tabs for indentation that seems to work well on Sublime but different on Github.

Comment: Actually, it looks like you've got a mix of spaces and tabs in your code. Can you share a link to the actual repo?

Comment: @Chris Here is the exact file that is showing error. https://github.com/RajeebTheGreat/axisbuilder/compare/shortcode-settings

Comment: @RajeebTheGreat, you definitely have mixed tabs and spaces (e.g. lines 64-65, 75-77 and 94-99). I don't know of any reason that Sublime Text would mix indentation characters on a single line like that... Is it possible that another user is committing changes using spaces instead of tabs?

Comment: @Chris Thanks for your help. I will have to ask another user. Cheers!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mixed tabs and spaces are causing this error. See the `.editorconfig` file for tab indentation and look at your code by highlighting all you have written where dotted are spaces and other lines are tabs:

[image: screenshot of code]

Comment: I thought this was going to be fixed automatically by `EditorConfig` plugin. Does that mean we have to change the tabs to spaces?

Comment: @JohnnyQ You can set:`"translate_tabs_to_spaces": false,` to `true` in your Sublime Text configuration. I keep it `false` globally and set it to `true` per syntax where needed.